# Indirect range from different sheet

Tags: excel

I would like to do the following:

On sheet 1, I have the following data:

```
A1:A5 = 1,2,3,4,5*

B1:B5 = A1,A2,A3,A4,A5*
```

On sheet 2 I would like to do the following:

```
SUM(INDIRECT(Sheet1!B1):INDIRECT(Sheet1!B5)
```

Comment: Not sure about your data, but SOM(sheet1!B1:B5) would be what I would start with.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to this, but this might work.

In worksheet `Hoja2` I got

[image]

In a different cell from another worksheet I got:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("Hoja2!"&INDIRECT(CELL("address";Hoja2!$B$1))&":"&INDIRECT(CELL("address";Hoja2!$B$5))))
```

And it works:

[image]

Anyways, INDIRECT is a volatile function and it may slow down:
https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2016/04/25/indirect-excels-most-evil-function/

If you explain what are you trying to achieve, maybe you can get suggested about new ways of aproaching.

Comment: So I am trying to make the timetable of my employer dynamic. Basically I have a starting point and an endpoint that represent the range of dates in different months, this sheet is called total. every month is represented in a different sheet. By using these start and endpoints I was hoping i could dynamically refer to the different employees. Because if I change these endpoints, i change the values in all the other sheets

Comment: You should Edit your original question and update with this new info. Add some example data (input) and your expected output